# NFS in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows, nfs

Can I have and use NFS in Windows 7 pro?

I tried downloading and installing it on Windows 7 Enterprise and it appears to work but I had no such luck with pro, I can't even download.

Comment: Client or server?  For client the answer appears to be yes:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754350.aspx

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't, at least not the "onboard" version.

NFS is part of the subsystem for Unix-based applications, which is limited to Enterprise and Ultimate

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Comparison_chart and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX#Subsystem_for_UNIX-based_Applications_.28SUA.29_and_separate_NFS

Third party implementations exist.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Any idea for a third party implementation? Do I have to do it on my own?